Wave equation with Dirac delta function as initial condition
I wonder if the wave equation
$$u_{tt}-\Delta u=0$$
with initial conditions
$$u(x,0)=\delta, \ \ \ u_{t}(x,0)=0$$
makes sense, both mathematically and physically. Is this equation well-posed?

How many dimensions do $x$ have?

I am interested in dimension 3. I wonder if it mathematically and physically makes sense.

Broadly, yes it does make sense. Even though the Dirac delta function isn't a proper function in the standard sense, it is a form of generalised function that you can think of as a kind of impulse.
If you substitute the given initial conditions into d'Alembert's formula, you very quickly get the solution
$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\delta(x-t) + \delta(x+t) \right)$$
meaning that the single delta impulse at $t = 0$ splits into two impulses of half size, one going left and the other going right at equal speeds.

Thank you ConMan. I was mainly interested in dimensions 3. So it would still make sense to think about the wave equation with Dirac delta as source?
